# selection sort returns zeros that aren't in my array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

This program has been mostly taken care of by my professor, what he left up to me was to write an array that will perform a selection sort on an array that is being scanned in from a file.

I wrote code with the help of my textbook that works almost perfectly. The output is wrong, however, in that the first 5 numbers in the output (which is supposed to be sorted in ascending order) are all 0 when the number 0 is not in the input file. The final 5 numbers in the array (the largest 5) are not present, either.

The output also lists the numbers from the input file in original, unsorted order, and it shows no errors.  All of the numbers are there.

My code for the method:

```
private static void selectionSort( int arr[], int cnt)
    {

    int index;
    int minIndex;
    int minValue;

        for (cnt=0; cnt < (arr.length-1); cnt++)
        {
            minIndex = cnt;
            minValue = arr[cnt];
            for (index = cnt + 1; index< arr.length; index++)
            {
                if (arr[index] < minValue)
                {
                    minValue = arr[index];
                    minIndex = index;
                }
            }
            arr[minIndex] = arr[cnt];
            arr[cnt] = minValue;
        }
    }
```

This is the output:

> original rands2: 75 62 110 144 108 146 121 119 61 164 170 34 78 41 89
>   84 74 132 156 160 94 55 76 97 48
>
> sorted rands2: 0 0 0 0 0 34 41 48 55 61 62 74 75 76 78 84 89 94 97 108
>   110 119 121 132 144

Are there any mistakes that I have made that would cause this to happen?

Comment: Is there any reason you're using both `arr.length` and `cnt`?  Are you sure you've set them up correctly?

Comment: Your code is running well on my machine with correct output

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't appear to be a typical implementation of a "delayed replacement sort" a.k.a. selection sort.

Importantly, after the inner loop is finished scanning for a new lowest element, you need to see if a new lowest has been found and, if so, do a swap.  Your algorithm lacks this critical step.  It can happen that the item at the outer loop index is **already** in order and does not need to be swapped.

Also, as noted above, it is unclear to me why your sort algorithm stores both the outer index and its corresponding value.  You just need the index, the elements in your collection aren't going anywhere (unless this is being used concurrently, that is .... but, whole 'nuther ball of wax).

Here is pseudocode for the delayed replacement sort algorithm:

```
Begin DELAYEDSORT
 For ITEM=1 to maximum number of items in list-1
    LOWEST=ITEM
    For N=ITEM+1 to maximum number of items in list
       Is entry at position N lower than entry at position LOWEST?
          If so, LOWEST=N
    Next N
    Is ITEM different from LOWEST
       If so, swap entry at LOWEST with entry in ITEM
 Next ITEM
End DELAYEDSORT
```

Just a few unsolicited notes about selection sort:

- It runs with a time complexity of O(n^2)
- Bubblesort also runs with a time complexity of O(n^2), but on unordered collections selection sort can be as much as 50% faster
- Selection sort is very costly on collections with a very large number of elements
- Selection sort can be faster on certain collections, even with a large number of elements, **if** the cost of performing a swap is high (selection sort minimizes the number of swaps needed to order the collection)
- Selection sort was the 1st sorting algorithm that I ever coded. It was much easier for me to understand than bubblesort (the algorithm aligned well with the manner in which I would go about ordering a collection)
- The only sorting algorithm of which I am aware with a **worse** time complexity than selection sort is the so-called "Stooge sort" which has a time complexity on the order of O(n^2.7)